# VERTICA Database :- how to get distinct count of "first names" where first name and last name are stored in single column?

Tags: sql, database, split, distinct, vertica

I'm new to Vertica DB and was facing a problem.
It is mostly like SQL but I have a Customer table

```
Customer Table 
NAME         | AGE   | SEX
JOHN KENY    |26     |M
JOHN CENA    |32     |M
JOHN MCCAIN  |35     |M
PETER PAN    |33     |M
SELENA GOMEZ |24     |F
```

Now i would like an output of a query to run on vertica DB to Fetch me DISTINCT customer first name i.e

```
NAME
JOHN
PETER
SELENA
```

I'm Trying the `SPLIT_PART()` function in Vertica but I am not able to execute the query correctly

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM
  (SELECT SPLIT_PART(NAME,' ',1) from Customer );
```

gives

> ERROR SYNTAX error at or near "Select"

I also tried

```
SELECT SPLIT_PART(SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM Customer,' ',1);
```

resulting in

> ERROR SYNTAX error at or near "Select"

but

```
SELECT SPLIT_PART('JOHN KENY',' ',1) ;
```

outputs

> JOHN

Comment: Try SELECT DISTINCT(NAME) FROM (SELECT SPLIT_PART(NAME, '   ',1) from Customer)

Comment: What error or output u r getting for all those.

Comment: No same Error 
SYNTAX error at or near "Select"

Comment: @RahulKumar its SYNTAX error at or near "Select"

Comment: I was trying to test, but I am not able to execute even a simple SPLIT_PART function in mySQL

Comment: @RahulKumar Its Vertica DB Not MySQL 
REF:-
 https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/String/SPLIT_PART.htm

Comment: what is the output of `SELECT SPLIT_PART(NAME,' ',1) from Customer ` ?

Comment: @RahulKumar The Output for SELECT SPLIT_PART(NAME,' ',1) from Customer is 
JOHN
JOHN
JOHN
PETER
SELENA

Comment: @RahulKumar thanks so problem Reduced to finding DISTINCT In above output

Comment: @RahulKumar `SELECT DISTINCT SPLIT_PART(NAME,' ',1) from Customer` 
Worked Thank you

Comment: The answers assume that there is only one first name and only one surname.  It wouldn't work for Helena Bonham Carter where the surname is Bonham Carter.  It also won't work for Anne Marie Jenkins.  It depends on the usage to which this is being put.  If it is for customer communication then bear in mind that Anne Marie might react badly to being called Anne and likewise Helena Carter might not be too happy either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should do the job :

```
select distinct SPLIT_PART(NAME,' ',1) from Customer
```

However, note that this is fragile. If this is a production environment (and not a simple exercise), I bet you'll end up with names containing spaces that will break your query.

Comment: Can You suggest better approach in that case ?

Comment: Your ideal solution would be to have a column for first name, and another one for last name. Then, you would'nt need the use of a split function. However, that would require you to have a clean data set, where both information are already split.